# how to prevent datepicker from selecting future date?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing the MVC application and  I  am using datepicker in the form.
I am using the below code in the form.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


        $(function () {
            $('.BirthDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
                yearRange:'1930:1995',
                buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Resource/Calender.jpg")',
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });

        $(".BirthDate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "01/01/1995" );
      });
```

I dont want to allow user to select future date. 
I have used year range but its allowing me to select any future month of 2013.
how to prevent it ? 
Which property we should used for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `maxDate` option http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

```
$(function () {
         $('.pickDate').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
             yearRange:'2011:2013',
             maxDate: 0,
             defaultDate: '01-01-2013'
         });

     });
```

In regards to the Op's recent changes, here is the revised code:

```
    $(function () {
        $('.BirthDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
            yearRange:'1930:1995',
            buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Resource/Calender.jpg")',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            maxDate:0
        });
    });

    $(".BirthDate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "01-01-1995" );
```

Comment: thanks Zee, one more thing, if I used the date range '2000-2012' then it shows the by default date in year box is 2000 , I want to show by default is 2012 , how to do that ?

Comment: Like this? `$( ".pickDate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "01/01/2012" );`

Comment: I set like this ,  yearRange:'2000:2012',setDate: "01/01/2012" but its not working...

Comment: `setDate` is a `method` so it isn't called during initialization like an `option` is, you have to call it on a seperate line after its initialized (the initialization code). http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Comment: thanks, but I am confused abt how to implement in my code, its hows default date is current date, I am asking for the end date as a default date.

Comment: See the updated code, and I highly suggest you read the manual to the `datepicker` object.

Comment: yes, I have read it and implmented it, please check the updated question, is this right ?

Comment: Your question has been answered, if you have another question, please post a new question.